# No funciona mi validacion de mi formulario con react, material-ui y formik aun asi teniendo todo correcto, al mi parecer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Estoy haciendo una aplicacion web con react donde tengo que hacer unas validaciones con formik junto con material-ui y ya anteriormente tenia un foumulario con validaciones que es casi igual a este y no me explico el porque ya que el codigo es exactamente el mismo ya que son las mismas validaciones, y no funcionan, el error es que no manda el formulario y no muetra los mensajes de errores, solo recarga la pagina y arriba en la url salen los valores de los formularios y en el otro no sale los valores de los campos en la url, si alguien puede ayudarme se lo agradeceria

```
  import React from 'react';

  import {
 Button,
 CssBaseline,
 TextField,
 FormControlLabel,
 Checkbox,

 Grid,
  Box, Typography, Container  } from '@material-ui/core';

  import {  Link } from "react-router-dom";

  import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

  import CopyrightText from '../components/CopyrightText';

  import * as yup from 'yup';

  import { useFormik } from 'formik';


 const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
 paper: {
 marginTop: theme.spacing(8),
 display: 'flex',
 flexDirection: 'column',
 alignItems: 'center',
 },
 avatar: {
 margin: theme.spacing(1),
 backgroundColor: theme.palette.secondary.main,
 },
 form: {
 width: '100%', // Fix IE 11 issue.
 marginTop: theme.spacing(1),
 },
 submit: {
 margin: theme.spacing(3, 0, 2),
 },
 }));

  const loginShema = yup.object({
              email: yup.string()
                .required('Your email please.')
                .email('Enter a valid email.'),
            password: yup.string()
                   .required('Your password please.')
                    .min(8, 'Your password is at least 8 characters long.')

 })



function LoginPage() {
 const classes = useStyles();
 const formik = useFormik({
  initialValues:{
    email:'',
    password:''
  },
  validationSchema: loginShema,
  onSubmit: (values) => {
   alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2))
   },

  })
  return (
   <body className="circuit-background">
    <Container component="main" maxWidth="xs" >
     <CssBaseline />
     <div className={classes.paper}>

     <Typography component="h1" variant="h5">
      Sign in
     </Typography>
    <form className={classes.form} noValidate>
      <TextField
        variant="filled"
        margin="normal"
        fullWidth
        id="email"
        label="Email Address"
        name="email"
        autoComplete="email"
        autoFocus
        onChange={formik.handleChange}
        value={formik.values.email}
        error={formik.touched.email && Boolean(formik.errors.email)}
        helperText={formik.touched.email && formik.errors.email}

      />
      <TextField
        variant="filled"
        margin="normal"
        fullWidth
        name="password"
        label="Password"
        type="password"
        id="password"
        autoComplete="current-password"
        onChange={formik.handleChange}
        value={formik.values.password}
        error={formik.touched.password && Boolean(formik.errors.password)}
        helperText={formik.touched.password && formik.errors.password}


      />
      <FormControlLabel
        control={<Checkbox value="remember" required color="primary" />}
        label="Remember me"
      />
      <Button
        type="submit"
        fullWidth
        variant="outlined"
        color="primary"
        className={classes.submit}
      >
        Sign In
      </Button>
      <Grid container>
        <Grid item xs>
          <Link >
            Forgot password?
          </Link>
         </Grid>
         <Grid item>
           <Link to="/SignUp">
             Don't have an account? Sign Up
           </Link>
         </Grid>
       </Grid>
     </form>
   </div>
   <Box mt={8}>
    <CopyrightText />
   </Box>
   </Container>
  </body>
  );
 }

export default LoginPage;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno amigo lo que te está pasando es el comportamiento por defecto de un formulario en html `<form />`, que es enviar los datos dentro de él a través del method `GET` en la URL.

Entonces para evitar esto, normalmente se usa `event.preventDrfault()` en el `onSubmit` del form, en tu caso como usas Formik debes de pasarle al form el handleSubmit para sobreescribir el comportamiento por defecto, quedaría algo así:

```
 <form className={classes.form} noValidate onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}>
```